# Intercept html button click

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

is there any possibility to intercept when a user clicks on a html button? I ve an webviewclient that load a login page with two buttons. Allow and Deny. I would you like to intercept when the deny button is pressed. (Deny and allow have the same basUrl and a js do the correct redirect).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not getting a callback to shouldOverrideUrlLoading() because that is only called if the user triggers the navigation - if you use jquery/javascript or some other kind of redirect, then it will not be called.

If you are in control of the web page, you can add can a JavaScriptInterface to call back to your Android app an handle it however you like here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

With JSI you simply register a function in your app and then call it in the page's javascript.

If you are not in control of the website, you can still inject the javascript yourself if you are familiar with the structure/DOM of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for implementing [`WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29%29), surely?

Comment: Then what's the actual problem? you get to snoop on every URL, so just check for the one that comes from the Deny button?

Comment: I tried it. I snooped with the debugger for every time the methos was invoked but with no success. The allow/deny buttons are managed with jquery. Can this causes of problem?

Comment: that would work only if a url is going to be loaded.