# Set an onClick listerner for a button inside a WebView in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

In my project I have a WebView in a fragment which loads a page from the internet. I want to set a listener on a button in that page so that when the user clicks on it I am able to move to a different fragment. I don't have the code for the webpage that is being loaded.

I was able to implement an onClick listener for the WebView itself [by using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926341), but I can't think of a way to intercept the button press specifically inside the WebView.

Any suggestions on how to implement something like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above answers were good workarounds, however, I ended up using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097149/10257053) and followed the [guide on Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) to enable JavaScript Binding. Note that `Android` interface needs to be used in the JavaScript file in order for the interception to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading to detect every URL changes on your WebViewClient and according to that you can open the particular fragment instead of setting click listener of a button in webview

Comment: This is a good idea, but,  the button's URL isn't static and can change. Is there any other way to intercept the button click?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview

Answer (score 1):

You should set up WebViewClient for your WebView . Here is a simple snippet:

```
    WebView webView;
    webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
    
    WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient(){
    
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
            if( url.equals("http://cnn.com") ){
                // Do the job here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to your button that calls `alert("abc")` in your web page.

Afterwards add following in your android code. The code will intercept your alert and you can implement your own code.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, final String message, JsResult result) {

                if (message.equals("abc"))
                {
                    result.cancel();                    
                    return true;
                }else 
                  return false;

            }
        });
```